# Halal photoshoot

Tags: halal-haram, hijab, clothing, photos

Salam Aleikum my brothers and sisters

I have this question that I wanted to ask you guys, because I have been thinking about it for, some time now.

I am about to start my own clothing line, (Inshallah) the category of the clothing is, tracksuits, hoodies and sweatshirts. Is it clothes to feel comfortable in. I wanted to do a photo shoot, were my friends are the models. So I have 2 questions that I wanted to ask about.

1: I’m i allowed to do a photo shoot?

2: Is it allowed to do a photo with a non - Muslim girl that is showing her hair?, or is it only allowed if a muslim girl wears hijab?

I hope you guys Can help me

Answer (score 0):

Wa aleikum Alsalam, I hope Your Clothing line be successful!

Firstly, Clothing is absolutely (Halal) but there are exceptions (Haram) such as inappropriate clothes (skinny that may show the parts of the body that is prohibited to show it, does not cover those parts of the body, etc.)

Secondly, ِAbout the photoshoots in general, there are difference in scholars sayings, to be honest there is a big scholar that prohibited photos.

As prophet muhammed (peace be upon him) said:
"The lawful is clear and the unlawful is clear, and between that are matters that are doubtful (not clear); many of the people do not know whether it is lawful or unlawful. So whoever leaves it to protect his religion and his honor, then he will be safe, and whoever falls into something from them, then he soon will have fallen into the unlawful. Just like if someone grazes (his animals) around a sanctuary, he would soon wind up in it. Indeed for every king is a sanctuary (pasture), and indeed Allah's sanctuary is what He made unlawful."

so I advice you to leave photo-shooting because this clothing line will be a way to earn money, and if photo-shooting was haram it will be a problem, and try to picture the clothing itself without the needing of a human (person) to wear it.

Thirdly, In addition of what I said (Secondly), also photo-shooting a mature women(girls) with hijab on head is not a good choice since women(girls) will try to show the beauty of the clothing, and without hijab either in clothing pictures or not it is also not a good choice since you are not 100% sure that all the people who will look to the picture in the website, application, shopping mall, etc. are women(girls), it is Haram, avoid it better.

Fourthly (adding from me), be sure whenever you do something or avoid something for the seek of Allah it will be better than if you did not, make your best and work on the clothing line plus do not disobey Allah or forget him.

Resources(most are arabic try to translate some if you want to be sure)

Firstly:https://binothaimeen.net/content/9652

Secondly:https://binbaz.org.sa/fatwas/20214/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%BA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%8A
(Hadith):https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/14/1

Thirdly:https://binbaz.org.sa/fatwas/28070/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AD%D9%81-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA

Comment: Thank you for your advice. May allah have mercy on all of you

Answer (score 0):

If the photo or video of non-Muslim women is not considered vulgar and the cover of the people in the photo is in accordance with the normal custom of their own society, it can be looked at and recognized without pleasure and interest, that is, without inciting lust or fear of falling into sin. And not knowing people is no different; Because non-Muslim women have no respect in this regard.

Ref: https://hawzah.net/fa/Magazine/View/4892/7659/96199

Answer (score -2):

Congrats on your clothing line and I wish you nothing but success! I think the photoshoot is totally fine. The clothing is for all kinds of people, so your photoshoot should showcase this as well. As long as the clothing is appropriate, I think there is no harm in this. :)